# Is it bad practice to connect wires of vastly different gauges?

Tags: batteries, cables, amperage, gauge

I would like to connect an Anderson plug with 25mm² cable to a 12V AGM battery so that I can easily connect and disconnect different devices which will conduct currents of varying amperage. I may connect 2mm² cable for conducting <500mA, 10mm² cable for charging at 20A or an 800W inverter using 25mm² cable for drawing up to 60A.

Is it bad practice to connect cables of vastly different gauges so long as the thinnest wire can comfortably conduct the magnitude of current required?

Can a wire’s gauge be too low to suitably conduct a very small current or is it a case of the thicker the wire the better the conduction regardless of the magnitude of the current?

Comment: Well, for high frequencies the larger wire is going to conduct proportionally less for how much copper is present.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are talking about connecting to a lead-acid battery it's pretty clear that there are no high frequency signals involved, so the inductance of the cable (and the skin effect) are not relevant in this case.

For low frequencies, larger diameter cables will provide less resistance to current flow so they are generally preferred. **Electrically**, it is OK to connect heavier cables to smaller cables. **However** there is some risk here and the practice may be prohibited by local electrical codes. For example, you connect a cable and plug designed for 30A to another wire that is rated for 15A. **You** know the limitation of the entire circuit is 15A, but someone else comes along, sees the 30A plug, and tries to draw 25A through the circuit. That would be a fire hazard.

Comment: Bad assumption.  If you are arc welding or using a brushed motor using a lead acid battery, **it's pretty clear** the battery can supply DC to the RF noise load. So the cable inductance needs to be much smaller than the circuit inductance unless it is decoupled with an RF cap.  So it might not be a factor, and the assumption is not given therefore cannot be assumed.

Answer (score -1):

You can determine the tolerance on voltage drop by the cable impedance.

So the cable only matters is the resulting voltage matters to you, which you can easily measure.

The wire gauge resistance and load surge current will determine the voltage drop on the cable's full path ( V+/Rtn) from basic Ohm's law.

The wire's **length/diameter ratio determines the inductance per unit length**, typ. 0.5 to 1uH/m in this range. If this matters, there are calculators for this.

## Drop voltage is load dependent

**ΔV = I²*R + j  L RMS{(I(ω,Φ)}** ( Fourier spectrum of all current components ω=2πf each with phase Φ  )
 **ΔV = I²*R + LdI/dt** ( for transients)

## Conclusion

If you know the voltage drop is acceptable (measured) and not reactive with some circuit (RF transmitter), the wire size may not matter.

In the case of a short cicuit, the weakest link becomes a fuse.